# Rails: How to simplify ".select(:my_field).map(&:my_field)"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

To get the invoice numbers of selected jobs I do:

```
Job.where(...).map(&:invoice_number)
```

Since the invoice numbers is all I need, I thought to add `select(:invoice_number)` (I assume the SQL query becomes more efficient this way):

```
Job.where(...).select(:invoice_number).map(&:invoice_number)
```

Is there a better way to do the same ? (the `.select(:invoice_number).map(&:invoice_number)` part seems inefficient to me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that this question is rather old, but in case anybody else checks this out, this can be achieved with `pluck` (http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck). As per http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#pluck "`pluck` makes it possible to replace code like: `Client.select(:id).map(&:id)` with `Client.pluck(:id)`"

Comment: Absolutely correct now, but only since 3.2, which was released some time after the original question (early 2012).  If you're stuck working on legacy Rails for some reason, you'll need a different method.

Answer (score 2):

You could always use `select_values`.  Something akin to:

```
Job.connection.select_values(Job.where(...).select(:invoice_number).to_sql)
```

This avoids the instantiation of ActiveRecord objects.

Comment: Fascinating... any idea if this is actually more efficient than the poster's original code?

Answer (score 0):

Would love to be proven wrong, but.. I don't think it's possible

Since all the active record methods are chainable, a method that returned an array of strings would break this. If such a method existed then it wouldn't be in AR, I can't think of where else to look..

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat).

```
invoice_numbers = Job.where(...).select('group_concat(invoice_number) as invoice_numbers').
                    first.invoice_numbers.split(',').map(&:to_i)
```

This approach is too long and is not very obvious, but it will run faster than

```
Job.where(...).select(:invoice_number).map(&:invoice_number)
```